# How to use multiple spring configuration files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a java spring configuration defined like so,

```
@Configuration
public class FirstConfiguration {

@Bean
FirstController firstController() {
    return new FirstController(firstService());
}

@Bean
FirstService firstService() {
    return new FirstServiceImpl(secondService());
}

}
```

Now the beans in this configuration depend on SecondConfiguration defined like so,

```
@Configuration
public class SecondConfiguration {

@Bean
SecondController SecondController() {
    return new SecondController(SecondService());
}

@Bean
SecondService secondService() {
    return new SecondServiceImpl();
}

}
```

How can I make use of the secondService()  bean in my FirstConfiguration?

Comment: You can import the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `SecondService` is a bean, you could inject it into the `firstService` method to configure another bean:

```
@Bean
FirstService firstService(@Autowired SecondService secondService) {
    return new FirstServiceImpl(secondService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `firstService` like this :

```
@Autowired
SecondService secondService
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the method `secondService()` directly when you import the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecondConfiguration.class)
public class FirstConfiguration {

    @Bean
    FirstController firstController() {
        return new FirstController(firstService());
    }

    @Bean
    SomeController someController() {
        return new SomeController(secondService());
    }
}
```

[Refer the Spring config import](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html)

Comment: and how will it get compiled? you missed some important detail - injecting a `SecondConfiguration` instance into the current configuration